# How do I override a xml value in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform xml to another xml with few conditions. One of condition is whenever my xml element has `DC19DAKHN` or `DC19D0000`, in transformed xml I would like to override them with value `MN019015J`.

How do I do this in XSLT?

My XML Code

```
<MyID>DC19DAKHN</MyID>
```

My xslt output is

```
<myID>DC19D0000</myID>
```

I want this to look like this instead

```
<myID>MN019015J</myID>
```

Do I use If Choose?

Comment: Just start from the identity transform and create a rule for your specific node.

Comment: Note: `<MyID>` is not the same thing as `<myID>`.

Comment: I agree with michael. Updated my suggestion in below post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyID/text()[.='DC19DAKHN']">MN019015J</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myID/text()[.='DC19D0000']">MN019015J</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```